# What is it? Rhymes with alphabet soup

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> A is for angry, an ancestor that's mad.
>      B is for barmy and blind but maybe not bad.
>      C is for coward in a cage with its claws.
>      D is not decent, it has dirt in its paws.
>      B in the ring again, biased and untrue.
>      H next is hot air which could melt into glue.
>
> It has all sorts of meanings from shoddy to mental.
>      And the creatures that make it are ultimately gentle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A is for angry, an ancestor that's mad.

> **Ape** means someone crazy or erratic, and our ancestors were apes. Going apesh... means being extremely angry.

B is for barmy and blind but maybe not bad.

> **Bat** is an animal that can't see. Not sure why "not bad", though. Batsh... is a word used when someone's gone insane.

C is for coward in a cage with its claws.

> A **chicken** lives in a cage and has claws. Chickensh... means coward.

D is not decent, it has dirt in its paws.

> **Dog** and has paws which can on occasion be dirty. Dogsh... means something that's of terrible quality.

B in the ring again, biased and untrue.

> A **bull** fights in a ring, and there's a stock market term "bullish bias". Bullsh... means something blatantly untrue.

H next is hot air which could melt into glue.

> **Horse** tissue is used for making glue. Horsesh... means nonsense (hot air).

It has all sorts of meanings from shoddy to mental.

> The censored word above can mean many different things.

And the creatures that make it are ultimately gentle.
What is it? Rhymes with alphabet soup

> Something animals make that rhymes with soup.

Comment: rot13(Puvarfr mbqvnp navznyf? Puvpxra vf nofrag, ohg ebbfgre'f bar bs gurz.)

Comment: rot13(Gur hygvzngryl tragyr pyhr jnf fb lbh pbhyq irevsl gb fbzr rkgrag gung lbh unq gur pbeerpg navznyf. Ynfg yrggref fcryy bhg TRAGYR qbT, ubefR, puvpxrA, onG, ohyY, ncR.) But otherwise fully solved! Well done.

Comment: @JonM Ohh I see now, pretty clever!

Answer (score 0):

is it a

> dragon- angry, barmy and might be blind, tied in a cage, has claws, dragon's breath that is fire is the hot air.